# Dump the [dump] tag off

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[dump](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dump) is useless. Most questions are about memory dumps, and are tagged memory already

Comment: Not only is it useless, as you say, but some people use it incorrectly: http://superuser.com/questions/895363/how-do-i-dump-all-entries-in-a-playlist-with-mplayer The term `dump` itself is a little vague.

Comment: +1 that one. Dump it *and* add `core-dump` (with same description) to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If all the questions are about memory dumps, then just instead of removing the tag, we can rename it as `memory-dump` as there isn't any tag with that name.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:**

Remove\Retag the tag where ever it is found to be inappropriate.

Comment: But not all are about memory dumps.

Comment: Then we should probably leave the `dump` tag as such and add a new tag for `memory-dump` so that the future questions at least will be more streamlined and should correct existing questions on memory dump as much as possible.

Comment: There's one about a playlist dump, a file dump, database dump, password dump, and even using dump as a verb for their own program

Comment: Confused about last comment !! Do you mean there are different dump tags available for playlist, database etc. and there is no need for memory dump separately? If so, I feel it is required, as memory-dump is something different than all these dumps specified by you.

Comment: Yes, that is the point. Get rid of [dump] by itself, and retag as [memory-dump] where appropriate, and remove from the questions where it just makes no sense whatsoever